# error build java project in vscodeThe project was not built due to "core does not exist". The project was not built due to "desktop does not exist"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, libgdx, game-development

I created a libgdx project using the building project tool.However when i build it in vscode , i met 2 errors

i expect everyone explain this state for me and recommend the solution.

what should i do next?

my java version:

openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-58)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-58, mixed mode, sharing)

this is the image for my problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWhU4.jpg)

Comment: You should provide more information. In the question, as much as you can as formatted text. Not as a link to an external source with an image.

Comment: there are a lot of Q&A with similar messages: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+project+was+not+build+due+to%22+%22does+not+exist%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com. check if your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.